# OCaml pattern matching on integers

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I have an assignment to fill in the following code stub:

```
let quad (x,y) = 
  match (x,y) with 
  | ... -> ...
  ...
```

where the `quad` function is supposed to take a tuple of ints as its argument, and return an algebraic data type representing the quadrant that the coordinates lie in.  I know exactly how to do it using if-clauses, but how would one do this using matching?  Is there a way to match integers with their sign?  I know I could even do it by matching on the value of a sign function.  I could write a function `sign` such that `sign 10 = 1` and `sign (-10) = -1` and so on, and then match on these values, but according to the code stub I shouldn't even do that.  Any hint on how to accomplish this?  Should I only do my matching on 0, and then if it's not 0 use if-clauses after the `->`?  Or is there some use of matching that can detect positive and negative integers?

Comment: What is the expected output? You can use `when` guards, but as I understand the assignment that would essentially just be a poor substitute for an if-expression. Since it's an assignment, perhaps it's supposed to be that contrived, but you're not making the objective of the assignment entirely clear so there might be some detail that gives it more sense.

Comment: Actually, you _can_ declare and use `sign` function - just match (0,0) as the first clause and do everything else in the second "catch all" clause. It will be an ugly solution but matching the stub provided :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly solution but *fits the code stub* :)

```
let quad (x,y) = 
  match (x,y) with 
  | (0, 0) -> `Center
  | _ -> begin
    let sign = function
      | 0 -> 0
      | x -> if x < 0 then -1 else 1
    in
    match (sign x), (sign y) with
    | -1, -1 -> `LeftBottom
    | -1, 1 -> `LeftTop
    | 1, -1 -> `RightBottom
    | 1, 1 -> `RightTop
  end
```

(I would *never* solve the task this way in real life)

UPD. As @Virgile mentioned in comments, the code above is not complete. There is an edge case which is not processed properly: when the point belongs to x- or y-axis (e.g. only one of its coordinates is zero). These cases can be obviously matched either in the outer `match`

```
...
| (0, _) -> `YAxis
| (_, 0) -> `XAxis
...
```

or in the inner `match` with clauses like

```
| 0, -1 | 0, 1 -> `YAxis
...
```

(or even in a more detailed manner if necessary - with different variants for positive and negative semiaxis)

Comment: there's a problem with this solution: it will fail to match `(0,y)` and `(x,0)` for any non-0 `x` or `y`.

Comment: @Virgile You're absolutely right, but this code wasn't intended to be a complete solution - it's just a quick (and quite dirty) sketch answering the initial question ("how to fit the solution to the code stub provided")...

Comment: Sure, my comment was mainly directed to someone who would be tempted to copy and paste your code without thinking further about it (I also completely agree with your statement that this is a very contrived way to solve the task that should not be used in real life).